# how to hide or disable CCMenuItemImage in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCMenuItem` declared in a `.h` file

```
CCMenuItemImage* button2 ;
```

I implemented it in an init statement of a `.m` file

```
 button2 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Levels.png" selectedImage:@"Levels.png" target:self selector:@selector(switchScenelevels)];
        levelbutton = [CCMenu menuWithItems:button2,  nil];
        levelbutton.position = levelstartpostion;
        [self addChild:levelbutton z:depthScore];
```

I need to hide this button when something occurs in my application.

I did the following to hide `button2`:

```
-(void)resetgameee
{
    [button2 setVisible:NO];

}
```

but no luck; it is still visible in the screen. I also do:

```
-(void)resetgameee
{
    [button2.isEnabled:NO];

}
```

which didn't work

How can I disable or hide this button?

Comment: Is working fine for me...did you check that resetgameee is executed? Try to make another button and when you click on that try to hide the button2, it should work.

Comment: the button selector is "switchScenelevels", so how is "resetgameee" called ?

Comment: Hide your CCMenu ..! That will hide your button.

Comment: @yannicuLar no no that is another selctor fires from the button...i need to hide the button2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with this:

`+ (id) itemFromNormalImage:     (NSString *)    value
selectedImage:      (NSString *)    value2
disabledImage:      (NSString *)    value3
target:     (id)    r
selector:       (SEL)   s`

if you want the button disappear you can put a transparent image in disabledImage, now
`[button2.isEnabled:NO];`
sould work and put the disabledImage on the screen